# Google Cloud Functions - Why are two positional arguments passed into my function by GCF?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function on Python 3.7 that does not take any input arguments. When I try to run it, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: google_cloud_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

The actual function code looks something like this (with different bash functions called):

```
import subprocess

def google_cloud_function():
    subprocess.call(["ls"], shell=True)
    subprocess.call(["pwd"], shell=True)
```

Why would this be the case?

Comment: Can you provide a description of the definition of your function?  How are you attempting to run it?

Comment: I've inserted code sample into the question. It is triggered by GCS bucket upload. The requirements.txt is fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A background Cloud Function triggered by something like Cloud Storage should have the following function signature:

```
def function(data, context):
    ...
```

The arguments need to be included even if you aren't using them.

Comment: So all cloud functions will have data and context passed into them it seems. Good to know. Cheers,

Comment: If they're background triggers, yes. If the trigger is HTTP requests, they'll get a `request` argument instead.

Comment: @DustinIngram thanks for the help, but could you please provide a full example? My function was like this : def deploy2():... my code... , and was getting the same errror Balkan was. Then tried your solution, but don't know if doing right, changed to this def test2(data, context):, but started getting error: `TypeError: test2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'`. Any tips? Cheers for the help

Comment: @RafaelPaz It sounds like you might be trying to deploy a function triggered by HTTP and not by a GCS event, in that case you'd want a function signature like `def test2(request)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @DustinIngram for your reply. I tried that, but having other issues, don't wanna ask much, but if you could help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938099/how-to-run-a-bash-script-inside-google-cloud-function-in-python?noredirect=1#comment96640261_54938099 and this https://serverfault.com/questions/956272/is-there-a-way-to-execute-a-bash-script-inside-google-cloud-functions-in-python would be much appreciated. Saw that you are very active about GCP topics and I'm pretty new. Cheers mate